# Using Key Value pairs in Hash as question and answer

Tags: ruby, hash, key-value

I'm working on an assignment in my code bootcamp, it involves ruby.

Create a program with a hash of countries & capitals such as the following:

```
cos_n_caps = {
    "USA" => "Washington, DC", 
    "Canada"=>"Ottawa",  
    "United Kingdom"=>"London",
    "France"=>"Paris", 
    "Germany"=>"Berlin", 
    "Egypt"=>"Cairo", 
    "Ghana"=>"Accra", 
    "Kenya"=>"Nairobi", 
    "Somalia"=>"Mogadishu", 
    "Sudan"=>"Khartoum", 
    "Tunisia"=>"Tunis",
    "Japan"=>"Tokyo", 
    "China"=>"Beijing",
    "Thailand"=>"Bangkok", 
    "India"=>"New Delhi", 
    "Philippines"=>"Manila", 
    "Australia"=>"Canberra", 
    "Kyrgyzstan"=>"Bishkek"
}
```

Ask the user for the capital of each country, and tell them if they are correct. Also, keep score and give them their score at the end of the quiz.

I want to know if I can somehow cycle through the list of keys and ask for user_input after each key and then check again value.

I've tried to use `hash.for_each{|key| puts key}`, but I don't know how to ask for `user_input` between the keys.

This is what I was going to do, unless I can find something easier:

```
s = "What is the capital of"
score = 0
count = 0

until count == 1
    puts "#{s} USA"
    a = gets.chomp.downcase
    if a == c["USA"].downcase
        puts "Congrats"
        score += 1
        count += 1
    else 
        puts "nope" 
        count +=1
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Hash#each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html#method-i-each) to loop through each pair of countries and capitals. In that loop, use [`Kernel#gets`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-gets) to read their answer and [`String#chomp`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/String.html#method-i-chomp) to remove the newline off their answer.

```
cos_n_caps.each do |country,capital|
  puts "What is the capital of #{country}?"
  answer = gets.chomp

  if capital.downcase == answer.downcase
    puts "Right!"
  else
    puts "Sorry, it's #{capital}."
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. The answer is always the simplest it seems. I always overthink things. 
Thanks ^-^